# malloc of matrix of struct - C

Tags: c, struct, malloc

I'm working on a game project. One of my struct contains a matrix of another struct. I  can't manage to get the malloc works. Here is my actual code :

```
m->tiles = malloc(sizeof(struct *tile)*width);

for (i=0; i<width ; i++){
    m->tiles[i] = malloc(sizeof(struct tile)*height);
}
```

And I got this error message :

```
 map.c:111:37: error: expected ‘{’ before ‘*’ token
 m->tiles = malloc(sizeof(struct *tile)*width);
```

I never did it before. Already allocate memory for int matrix but never struct matrix.

Thank you.

EDIT : Thank you BLUEPIXY your answer works. But I think I didn't well defined my struct :

```
struct map{

   int map_width;  // Nombre de tiles en largeur
   int map_height; // Nombre de tiles en hauteur

   struct tile **tiles; // ensemble des tiles de la map
};
```

It should be "struct tile ***tiles" ?

Comment: `struct *tile` --> `struct tile*` typo

Comment: it's not a typo, there are two asterisks..

Comment: What type is `m->tiles`?

Comment: That the subject of my edit, it's "struct **tile" but it should be "struct ***tile" no ?

Comment: Then it should be `sizeof(struct tiles) * width` probably.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
struct map{
   int map_width;
   int map_height;
   struct tile **tiles;
};

...

m->tiles = malloc(sizeof(struct tile*)*height);

for (i=0; i<height ; i++){
    m->tiles[i] = malloc(sizeof(struct tile)*width);
}
```

explanatory notes

```
Type **var_name = malloc(size*sizeof(Type *));
```

or

```
Type **var_name = malloc(size*sizeof(*var_name));
```

Comment: Are you sure it's not "struct tile ***tiles" as the matrix store the pointer to the structure (so ** for a matrix and * for adress of the structure)?

Comment: just dereference in your head: `tiles[i] == (*(tiles+i))` and `tiles[i][j] == *(*(tiles+i)+j)`, now count the stars :)

Comment: Yup I agree. But when you defined a struct referencing another struct, you code : "struct *other_struct"  (where *other_struct is just one structure). That's why i'm asking :).

Comment: @romz34 receive(left) side type is  pointer to  pointer  when the return value to secure the pointer by `malloc`.

Answer (score 2):

Using a `struct tile **tiles` is sufficient. Think of it like this:

`struct tile_array *tiles` would obviously suffice to point to an array of `tile_array` pointers. Now to avoid the additional `struct` replace `tile_array` with a pointer to a tile. As a result, you have a pointer to a pointer of type `tile`. The pointer to `tile` represents the beginning of an array of `tile`s. The pointer to the pointer to `tile` represents the beginning of an array of such pointers.

Answer (score 0):

This

```
m->tiles = malloc(sizeof(struct *tile)*width);
```

should be

```
m->tiles = malloc(width * sizeof(struct tile *));
```

So, the fixed code should look like

```
m->tiles = malloc(width * sizeof(struct tile *));
if (m->tiles == NULL)
    cannotAllocateMemoryAbortPlease();
for (i = 0 ; i < width ; ++i)
    m->tiles[i] = malloc(height * sizeof(struct tile));
```

Comment: Oh, yes I made a mistake. it is :  "m->tiles[i] = malloc(sizeof(struct tile)*height);

Comment: @romz34 for the next time you post a question, don't re-type the code, just copy it from the editor and paste it as is, otherwise you could event accidentally fix the problem without noticing.

Comment: note on the side: your code allocates the matrix column major

Comment: I didn't check what the code does, I just tried to point out the mistakes the OP made, and why the compiler issued the error, but I was not interested in guessing what the OP was trying to do.